# Can not shut down Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown, 15.04

I upgraded my Kubuntu system from 14.10 to 15.04. Now I can not shut down or log out from the system using the gui's menu. When I click on the shutdown button, ksmserver goes to 100% CPU and nothing happens.

Does anyone have the same problem? Any ideas for a resolution?

Comment: Is this happening directly after your update? I had the same issue. You can press CTRL+ALT+F1, and then press CTRL+ALT+DEL.

Comment: Yes, it never happends in 14.10  version. I use shutdown from terminal now, but this really bothers me.

Comment: So the problem still persists? I thought, it was only once.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me also with Plasma 5.3. I had to go back to Plasma 5.2 to be able of shutting down from the gui menu.